# Is there a way to do IPFS pubsub message forwarding if the intermediate node does not subscrive to the topic?

Tags: go, ipfs, libp2p

Is there a way to do IPFS pubsub message forwarding if the intermediate node does not subscrive to the topic?
し
A <-> B <-> C
As above, there are configurations where A and C are not directly connected but A and B or B and C are connected.
＊A, B and C are IPFS Peers.

If C subscribes to a Topic and A publishes a message, C cannot receive the message unless B subscribes.
＊Tested with Kubo v0.15.0.

Is there a way for C to receive message even if B has not subscribed?
If so, please let me know.

If C subscribes to a Topic and A publishes a message, C cannot receive the message unless B subscribes.
＊Tested with Kubo v0.15.0.

Comment: Hi! I don't know the answer, but I've tried to signal-boost your question by posting it to [our forums](https://discuss.ipfs.tech/t/is-there-a-way-to-do-ipfs-pubsub-message-forwarding-if-the-intermediate-node-does-not-subscribe-to-the-topic/15820). I'll try to update this question if there's activity there.